# Function calling from STL max function

Tags: c++, function, stl

I have two function calling inside C++ STL max function. Which function will be called first ?First one or Second one?

```
 max(rec(a,a[lev+1],lev+1,n,ar),rec(a,(a[lev]+a[lev+2])/2,lev+1,n,ar));
```

Comment: It's implementation defined, IIRC.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: What do you mean by implementation defined .

Comment: The "implementation" is the compiler, and it might do whatever it pleases when it evaluates function arguments. It might not even have a specific fixed and set order, for some calls it could do it in one order, for some other in a completely different order.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: "Implementation defined" **does** mean it has to be in the documentation, so it would be rather tricky to document a varying order. But since C++17 it's actually _indeterminately sequenced_. It doesn't need to be documented.

Answer (score 2):

The only requirement is that there is *an* order. Once the compiler starts evaluating one argument, it has to finish that before it starts evaluating the other argument.

But the optimizer in the compiler may pick on a case-by-case basis what it thinks is best, so you cannot predict up front what choice the compiler will make.